# How do I use a wireless router as a switch? (even WiFi access)

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have a TP-Link router (without wireless) connected to my modem which has this subnet : `192.168.0.*` - that work fine.

However I need a wireless connection too. My wireless router had this IP given by the TP-Link router: `192.168.0.13`.

I have a [Netgear WGR614 Wireless-G Router](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/WGR614v1) which gain 192.168.0.13 but I need that gives IPs in the same subnet as a TP-Link router.

If the person connect to my WiFi it should receive an IP like `192.168.0.*`. I already tried to disable the DHCP server in the Netgear router but it's not working.

How can I do that?

Comment: how did you connect the two routers? you should *not* be using the 'internet' ethernet socket on the router acting as a switch

Comment: I connect the modem in the TP link, then a cable ethernet from the TP Link I connect in the WAN port in the NETGEAR router.
I should not do that ?

Comment: Thats your problem. Posting that as an answer ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do *not* connect the ethernet cable from the tp link to the wan port on the netgear router. connect together regular *lan* ports on both.

Comment: UUUUUUffff, once I read this it was sooo obvious. And the the netgear (read secondary, inner, local, wifi) router should not act as a DHCP server.

Comment: He mentioned turning it off. And its totally less than obvious - I found this out in a moment of AUGGHGHHH

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you shouldn't have 2 DHCP enabled routers on the same network as it will just be pure luck which range the connected PC gets allocated to. BUT using my method below they shouldn't conflict with each other...

Within the DHCP options of each router you should have a 'scope' or 'range' where you can specify different rages within the same subnet to the 2 routers, say 192.168.0.15 - 192.168.0.45 for router 1 and 192.168.0.50 - 192.168.0.100 for router 2.

Comment: It would be better to disable DHCP on the TP link and use static IP's for connected PC's (+ the Netgear) then use DHCP on the Netgear with a scope away from the static IP's.